# Setting the background of an email template from servlet.ImageServer

Tags: email-template

I created an email template with this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<center>
<h1> Test </h1>
</head>
<body background="https://ap2.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01528000000vBfW&oid=00D280000011MW7&lastMod=1457578336000" />
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

The background image is not showing but it has the text.

Comment: Your image is not publicly available. Try open that URL from another browser/incognito mode.

Comment: it is externally available

Comment: It's not because I get "Server not found" when I try to open it

Comment: oh, wait..........